# Finding item of array base on the ng-repeater index in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In my application i have 2 array of object.`layout` array is for creating twitter bootstrap layout.this array is like below :

```
 $scope.layout = [
  {c:[{size:12}]},
  {c:[{size:2},{size:3},{size:4},{size:3}]},
  {c:[{size:3},{size:5},{size:4}]}
];
```

you can see how this array work in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nefoz/1/edit?html,js,output).the other array is items array and this array is like below:

```
 $scope.items =[
   {row:1,column:0,names:['Jack','Daniel']},
   {row:3,column:3,names:['Eli','Bill']},
   {row:2,column:1,names:['Fred','David']}
];
```

and this is the repeater that i used :

```
<div ng-repeat="(ri,r) in layout" class="row">

  <div ng-repeat="(ci,c) in r.c" class="col-md-{{c.size}} col-sm-{{c.size}} col-xs-{{c.size}} col-lg-{{c.size}}  bi"> Row{{ri}}-Column{{ci}}
         //Maybe other repeater come here

  </div>
</div>
```

now i want when i want to display `Jack , Daniel` in `row 1 column 0`  and this 1 and 0 is r and c in repeater of first and second repeater.so when the repeater create `row 2 column 1` also repeat on $scop.item and find the related names. but i don't know how to find items in $scope.item.and this is my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/nefoz/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Are you able to modify your arrays prior to DOM display? Combining the two arrays or modifying the second array two be indexed by the row and column numbers would be much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="(ri,r) in layout" class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="(ci,c) in r.c" class="col-md-{{c.size}} col-sm-{{c.size}} col-xs-{{c.size}} col-lg-{{c.size}} bi">
    {{getNames(ri, ci)}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `getNames` is defined in controller:

```
$scope.getNames = function(r, c) {
  var items = $scope.items;
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].row == r && items[i].column == c) {
      return items[i].names;
    }
  }
  return '';
};
```

#### Demo: http://jsbin.com/sumuwigo/1/edit